# Why HTTP HEAD Request is not caught by routes.MapRoutes() while HTTP GET is?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have a .NET controller that handles image requests.

There is a URL rewriting rule in the web.config that converts `http://localhost/images/1809x1280/image1.jpg`
to `http://localhost/image/get/image1.jpg/1809/1280`

I then have the following `RouteConfig` rule

```
    routes.MapRoute()
        name: "Images",
        url: "image/get/{filename}/{width}/{height}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Image", action = "Get" }
    );
```

When I perform a `HTTP GET` request, the action is correctly routed to the correct control and I get the expected `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response, however as I change the HTTP verb from `GET` to `HEAD` I receive a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` response.

Having placed a breakpoint into my `ImageController.Get()` method I noticed that only the `HTTP GET` request was hitting it.

Having then placed a breakpoint inside `Application_BeginRequest` of `Global.asax.cs`, the breakpoint is hit for both `HTTP GET` and `HTTP HEAD` requests.

When the request was `HTTP HEAD` I had the following properties of the `Request` object:

`RawUrl "/images/1809x1280/image1.jpg"  string`

`Url    {http://localhost/image/get/image1.jpg/1809/1280}   System.Uri`

which are correct and indicate that the `web.config` rewriting rule has kicked in, however the `ImageController.Get()` is never hit.

It seems to be a problem with the `routes.MapRoute()` at this point but I'm not sure how to go about and investigate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it was simpler than I thought.

I looked everywhere except looking at my controller action which was decorated with only the `[HttpGet]` attribute, replacing that with the following has fixed it:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
public ActionResult Get(string imageName){
...
}
```

Comment: You bake your cake and it eat too... hahaha

Comment: It seems soo :)